# JSON - searching through keys with variable names (unknown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

Total JSON noob here. I'm trying to cycle through some JSON to pull out the first image from an array inside the object, and after 4 hours of having at it, I've decided I probably need some help.

I'm able to pull every value I need out of the object where I know the key, but I have some data that has non consistent key names that I need to basically iterate through looking for a partial match and then pulling the first on of these results.

The Json structure of the unknown element is structured like this:

```
"custom_fields": {
    "content_0_subheading": [
      "Title text"
    ],
    "content_1_text": [
      "Some text"
    ],
    "content_2_image": [
      [
        "http://staging.livelivelyblog.assemblo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/wellbeing-260x130.jpg",
        260,
        130,
        true
      ]
    ],
    "content_2_caption": [
      ""
        ]
}
```

What I'm after is the content_2_image in this case, but in another entry it could be content_20_image for all I know (there's a lot of data being pulled).

Any ideas of the best way to cycle through these unknown keys looking for a partial match on '_image' in the key or something, would be VERY appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: do you control the JSON structure or is this some API call response?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't just search through every field with a partial match, so you'll have to iterate through every field and then check the field names for the match. Try something like this:

```
var json = {
  "content_0_subheading": [
    "Title text"
  ],
  "content_1_text": [
    "Some text"
  ],
  "content_2_image": [
    [
      "http://staging.livelivelyblog.assemblo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/wellbeing-260x130.jpg",
      260,
      130,
      true
    ]
  ],
  "content_2_caption": [
    ""
  ]
}

for (var key in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (/content_[0-9]+_image/.test(key)) {
            console.log('match!', json[key]); // do stuff here!
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, what we're doing is:

1) Loop through keys of json object `for (var key in json)`

2) Ensure the json has the property, and we're not accessing keys we don't want `if (json.hasOwnProperty(key))`

3) Check if key matches the regular expression `/content_[0-9]+_image/`

3a) Basically, test if it matches `content_ANY NUMBERS_image` where `ANY NUMBERS` is equal to at least one digit or more

4) Use that data however you please `console.log(json[key])`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You could use `for ... in`

```
for (key in object) {
    // check match & do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var json = JSON.parse(YOUR_JSON_STRING).custom_fields, //Fetch your JSON
    image;                                             //Pre-declare image
for(key in json){                               //Search each key in your object
    if(key.indexOf("image") != -1){             //If the index contains "image"
        image = json[key];                //Then image is set to your image array
        break;                                  //Exit the loop
    }
}
/*
image[0]  //the URL
image[1]  //the width
image[2]  //the height
image[3]  //your boolean
```