# Match data in json field mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

Here is my table screen-shot:
[image]

If I have single category id like: 3 or 11 to match in this complete json.

I tried json_contains or json_search.

Comment: add code what you tried ?

Comment: You should normalize your database: Add a table that links your items to categories.

Comment: This answer might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910976/json-searching-through-keys-with-variable-names-unknown

Comment: @AbdullaNilam, I am working on Laravel, need to convert this query Tax::where('category_ids','like','%'.'"'.$id.'"'.'%')->get(['id']);

Comment: @Yogita any update on the answer ?

Comment: As I told you that I am using Tax::where('category_ids','like','%'.'"'.$id.'"'.'%')->get(['id']); this and is working for me but I am not sure that it is right way to get data from json field

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Tax::where("json_contains('category_ids','like','%'.$id.'%')")->get(['id']);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer appreciate your effort. Buddy its and code. `json_contains` + where. so its simply drives what was did