# Is there a python function to search json for key

Tags: python

I'm using the google maps API to lookup "long_name" for "administrative_area_level_1" and "country" for a bunch of different latitudes and longitudes.

How do I extract them dynamically?

The JSON doesn't look the same every time. Here is an example of some JSON for a location.

```
    {'plus_code': {'compound_code': 'F68J+XJ Santander, Spain',
  'global_code': '8CMRF68J+XJ'},
 'results': [{'address_components': [{'long_name': '38',
     'short_name': '38',
     'types': ['street_number']},
    {'long_name': 'Avenida de la Reina Victoria',
     'short_name': 'Av de la Reina Victoria',
     'types': ['route']},
    {'long_name': 'Santander',
     'short_name': 'Santander',
     'types': ['locality', 'political']},
    {'long_name': 'Cantabria',
     'short_name': 'S',
     'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
    {'long_name': 'Cantabria',
     'short_name': 'Cantabria',
     'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
    {'long_name': 'Spain',
     'short_name': 'ES',
     'types': ['country', 'political']},
    {'long_name': '39005', 'short_name': '39005', 'types': ['postal_code']}],
   'formatted_address': 'Av de la Reina Victoria, 38, 39005 Santander, Cantabria, Spain',
   'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 43.4674468, 'lng': -3.7681911},
    'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
    'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 43.46879578029149,
      'lng': -3.766842119708497},
     'southwest': {'lat': 43.4660978197085, 'lng': -3.769540080291502}}},
   'place_id': 'ChIJa7pGPwRLSQ0RiO12N_vlLlk',
   'plus_code': {'compound_code': 'F68J+XP Santander, Spain',
    'global_code': '8CMRF68J+XP'},
   'types': ['establishment', 'point_of_interest', 'tourist_attraction']},
  {'address_components': [{'long_name': '1',
     'short_name': '1',
     'types': ['street_number']},
    {'long_name': 'Calle Familia Real',
     'short_name': 'Calle Familia Real',
     'types': ['route']},
    {'long_name': 'Santander',
     'short_name': 'Santander',
     'types': ['locality', 'political']},
    {'long_name': 'Cantabria',
     'short_name': 'S',
     'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
    {'long_name': 'Cantabria',
     'short_name': 'Cantabria',
     'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
    {'long_name': 'Spain',
     'short_name': 'ES',
     'types': ['country', 'political']},
    {'long_name': '39005', 'short_name': '39005', 'types': ['postal_code']}],
   'formatted_address': 'Calle Familia Real, 1, 39005 Santander, Cantabria, Spain',
   'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 43.4681601, 'lng': -3.768483299999999},
    'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
    'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 43.46950908029149,
      'lng': -3.767134319708497},
     'southwest': {'lat': 43.4668111197085, 'lng': -3.769832280291502}}},
   'place_id': 'ChIJtWZvjxlLSQ0Re6B7ZO_bD3Y',
   'plus_code': {'compound_code': 'F69J+7J Santander, Spain',
    'global_code': '8CMRF69J+7J'},
   'types': ['street_address']},
  {'address_components': [{'long_name': '1',
     'short_name': '1',
     'types': ['street_number']},
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Toby, can you add a json that I can assign to a variable so i can help you better?

Comment: It's unclear what the top JSON actually is (a list or a dict) since you're only showing a part of it. It's also unclear exactly what values you want to get, can you edit your question to show the full JSON and an example of the expected output?

Comment: This can be done, but not with a single Python function. Put some valid JSON data in you question for a demonstration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have a look at pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
json_normalize(your_json)
```

And then do the dynamic extracting using the pandas API? By basically doing a query on the dataframe from your json? You also might want to look at PySpark too if youre talking big data.

> https://hackersandslackers.com/json-into-pandas-dataframes/
>
> https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html

Answer (score 0):

You could for-loop through the entire Json like so:

```
for key in myJson:
    if(key == "key_to_find"):
        print(f'Found {key} in myJson')
```

You could also look into hasOwnProperty: `json.hasOwnProperty(key)`

Referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18911202/11317776)

Comment: note that `hasOwnProperty` is a JavaScript idiom (not Python), you'd just do `if key in myJson:` to check if it's there, or `myJson.get(key)` to get the value of a key that might not exist