Search through a map for specific keys
Im trying to solve a particularly unique situation, and I was wondering whether it was even possible.
I have a sample json parameter map like this:
{
"destinationCity": "seattle",
"checkInTime" : "9:45 am"
}

now the thing is that we're using a map like this to call an API, whose inputs needs some of these values. However, depending on the use case, what could happen is that the key "checkInTime" could also be "HotelCheckInTime" or "tripStartTime" etc.
Now, we don't want to have a huge switch case or if else statements saying that if it is useCase1, map the checkInTime to checkInTime, if it is useCase2, map the checkInTime to HotelCheckInTime.
In Javascript, is there a way to do sort of a search which basically does something like this:
if the incoming json map has one of these values(checkInTime, TripCheckInTime), use the value from that particular Key which is present.
I know probably I can do a loop with a contains check on the entire keySet, but I'm wondering if javascript has something built-in for the same.
Thank you!

Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910976/json-searching-through-keys-with-variable-names-unknown  You can write your code to look for any key that ends with "InTime"
